# How to dynamically create files from lines in a text file

Tags: php

How can I use PHP to loop through a text file and create file `xxx.txt` base of the text of each line?

For example I have a file named `files.txt` and it contains

**files.txt**

```
red 
pink 
purple 
deep purple 
indigo 
blue 
light blue 
cyan 
teal 
green
```

I already tried this

```
<?php
$file = fopen("files.txt","r");

while(! feof($file))
  {
  echo fgets($file). "<br />";
  $fileName = fgets($file);
  $myfile = fopen($fileName.'.txt, "w");

  }

fclose($file);
?>
```

but this only create last `green.txt`.

Comment: See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php, what are you trying to do? create a file for each value in the file? And write what to it?

Comment: Why not just use [copy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)?

Comment: For god sake why are you down voting his question?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$handle = fopen("path/to/files.txt", "r");
$filesToCreate = [];
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {

        // you may need to add the full path here..
        $filesToCreate[] = $line . '.txt';
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}

foreach ($filesToCreate as $newFile) {
    $createdFile = fopen($newFile, 'w');
    fclose($createdFile);
}
```